# Replace specific values in dataframe with a random row's values

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following df

```
df <- read.table(text = "team id result result_number
A 1 999 999
A 2 cat 45
A 3 dog 50
B 4 999 999
B 5 three 60
B 6 four 30
C 7 999 999
C 8 rabbit 45
C 9 monkey 11
D 10 dog 12
D 11 999 999
D 12 basket 10", header = T)
```

For every row that has a 999 in the `result` category, I'd like to replace that value (and the corresponding `result_number` value) with the values from a random row *within* the same team (e.g. random within A, B, C, or D) that is not 999.

So here's an example output:

```
df <- read.table(text = "team id result result_number
A 1 cat 45
A 2 cat 45
A 3 dog 50
B 4 four 30
B 5 three 60
B 6 four 30
C 7 rabbit 45
C 8 rabbit 45
C 9 monkey 11
D 10 dog 12
D 11 basket 10
D 12 basket 10", header = T)
```

I can't figure out an elegant way of doing this in dplyr without a really clumsy external function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grouped by 'team', loop `across` the 'result', 'result_number', columns, `replace`, where the value is 999 with a `sample` of elements that are not equal (`!=`) to 999, and return a single value

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(team) %>% 
   mutate(across(result:result_number,
      ~ replace(., as.character(.)==  "999", 
          sample(.[as.character(.) != "999"], 1)))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 4
   team     id result result_number
   <chr> <int> <chr>          <int>
 1 A         1 dog               45
 2 A         2 cat               45
 3 A         3 dog               50
 4 B         4 four              30
 5 B         5 three             60
 6 B         6 four              30
 7 C         7 monkey            45
 8 C         8 rabbit            45
 9 C         9 monkey            11
10 D        10 dog               12
11 D        11 dog               10
12 D        12 basket            10
```

Comment: Just a quick note for OP about comparing the character column `result` to a numeric value `999` (eg `. == 999` and `. != 999`) that values are coerced to the same type in the following precedence: character, complex, numeric, integer, logical, and raw before comparison.

Comment: @LMc  yes, that is true.  I was making use of the coercion in `replace` unlike in `case_when` which is strict for type

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  To be safe, I updated with `as.character`

Comment: @akrun: Could you please help: df %>%  group_by(team) %>%  mutate(across(contains("result"), ~ifelse(.==999,sample(.,size=1, replace = TRUE),.))) . Some 999 remain why? thanks!

Comment: @TarJae because you are `sample`ing from the whole column which also include 999.  You may change the `sample` to `sample(.[. != 999], 1, replace = TRUE)`. also the type conversion as LMc's comments is relevant

Comment: Many thanks Master akrun!!!

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks, Akrun. Could you explain what's going on with this line: `replace(., as.character(.)==  "999"` Is this saying "replace the current value ONLY if it's equal to 999... and then, if so, replace it with `sample(.[as.character(.) != "999"]` otherwise leave it as is? And is the `1` "leave it as is?"

Comment: @Parseltongue It is converted to `character` because one of the column is character, In `replace`, when we specify the logical veector (`as.character == "999"`), it returns TRUE only where the elements are 999.  in the replacement, subset the column where value is not equal to 999 and get a sample of size 1 (or else it will sample the length of `.[as.character(.) != "999"]`

Answer (score 2):

This result was created with the help of akrun! Many thanks!

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(team) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("result"), ~ifelse(.==999, sample(.[. != 999], 1, replace = TRUE),.)))
```

```
team     id result result_number
   <chr> <int> <chr>          <int>
 1 A         1 cat               50
 2 A         2 cat               45
 3 A         3 dog               50
 4 B         4 four              60
 5 B         5 three             60
 6 B         6 four              30
 7 C         7 monkey            45
 8 C         8 rabbit            45
 9 C         9 monkey            11
10 D        10 dog               12
11 D        11 dog               12
12 D        12 basket            10
```